# Using records with generics that require a default constructor

Tags: f#

I'd like to use a record with a data structure that requires its types to have a default constructor.  Unfortunately this results in a compile time error.

Aside from changing the data structure (not possible here).  Or changing the record to a type (would require adding in type annotations ever where) what options do you have in this type of scenario?

I suppose one could wrap the record inside a struct, but that feels like hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the [CLIMutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289724.aspx) attribute to your record.

Comment: This is exactly what I want...kinda.  Based on this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/07/19/more-about-fsharp-3.0-language-features.aspx F# compiler emits a default constructor and property setters into the generated IL for this type (though those features are not exposed to F# code).  You have to wonder, why wouldn't this feature be available to F# code! (which is what I need).

Comment: So CLIMutable does not satisfy a generic constraint that a type have a default constructor, but only when the constraint is in F# code, is that the problem? Yuck. I might send a question to fsbugs@microsoft.com about that, maybe it's not too late to get that fixed in F# 3.1, since the preview release only just came out.

Comment: It is actually the opposite.  The attribute can emit the default constructor in IL, so libraries using your F# code will see it.  What makes no sense is that if you try to use the record in F# code with say a C# library that requires it, at that point in time it is not recognized and errors!

Answer (score 7):

This appears to have been fixed in F# 3.1.  Consider this code:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type R = {a : int}

let f<'a when 'a : (new : unit -> 'a)>() = new 'a()

let r = f<R>()
```

In F# 3.0 (VS 2012), you get an error on the last line - `error FS0001: A generic construct requires that the type 'R' have a public default constructor`

But it works in F# 3.1 (not RTM yet, but [public pre-release was earlier this week](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2013/06/27/announcing-a-pre-release-of-f-3-1-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx))

Comment: Will F# 3.1 run on VS 2012?